# How to redirect specific IP addresses

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-crawler

I would like to redirect spiders from visiting my blog. I am looking for a solution that can be embedded into the webpage HTML so that the spider is redirected away before affecting my page visit count. Is this possible with say javascript, IP address of the spider, and spider's referring url?

Comment: do you want them to still index your page?

Comment: use some intelligent page view counting, like analytics, spiders will use many changing ip's its not practicable to do this

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Javascript alone, it is possible with PHP or a combination of Javascript and PHP but this is usually handled by `.htaccess` files:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 123.45.6.7
deny from 012.34.5.
allow from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a web crawler? If so disabling those would also lower your count because no one will visit your website because it will not be indexed by search engines if they cannot crawl your websites with spider.

If you wish to stop crawlers visiting certain parts of your website use something called robots.txt I will provide a wikipedia article on it and you can research further how to use it.

I suggest not disallowing crawling in all parts of your websites, just some parts which you do not want to be crawled.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Answer (score 0):

If your visit counter is made up with javascript (like Google Analytics) it won't be a problem since crawlers don't execute javascript.

If the visit counter is made on the server side just insert something like this before the visit counter:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'bot') !== false){
   die();
}
```